# возврат заднего фона элемента

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте! Я нажимаю на конпку, хочу что бы цвет заднего фона одного элемента, был присвоин другому элементу. Раньше я делал так.

```
public void button1Click(View view) {
 textView3.setBackgroundColor((ColorDrawable)textView1.getBackground().getColor());
}
```

Сейчас, метод

> getColor()

**cannot resolve method**
т.е его нет. Возможно, кто-то уже сталкивался с такой проблемой. Подскажите. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Навряд ли Вы раньше передавали `ColorDrawable` в `setBackgroundColor(int color)`. Скорее всего было что-то вроде:

```
textView3.setBackgroundColor(((ColorDrawable)textView1.getBackground()).getColor());
```

Ошибка возникает т.к. [`View.getBackground`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getBackground()) возвращает тип [`Drawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html) у которого нет метода `getColor`. Чтобы получить доступ к методу выполняется приведение к классу [`ColorDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ColorDrawable.html). Скобки нужны чтобы сначала привести к нужному классу, затем вызвать метод.

Comment: Уважаемый default locale! Большое Вам спасибо! Вы совершенно правы! Я так и делал, но видимо забыл обернуть еще раз скобками. Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: @Anton Пожалуйста! Удачи!